# Cannot find control with name: 'aluno.id'

Tags: angular

Estou tentando enviar o id do aluno, porém esta dando esse erro.

Marcar-presenca.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
  <div class="mdl-grid mdl-cell--4-col">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Código do Aluno</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" formControlName="aluno.id" (keyup)="onSubmit()">
          <mat-error *ngIf="formulario.get('aluno.id').hasError('required')">
            Campo obrigatório
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
```

Marcar-presenca.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
      aluno: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [null]
      }),
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log('chamou');
    if (this.formulario.valid) {
      console.log('1 - ', this.formulario.value);
      this.presencaService.post(this.formulario.value).subscribe(() => {
        this.abrirSnackBar('Presença registrada com sucesso!');
          // window.location.href = '/novo';
        this.formulario.reset();
      }, err => {
        this.abrirSnackBar(err.error.message);
      });
    }
  }
```

> MarcarPresencaComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'aluno.id'
>       at _throwError (forms.js:3357)
>       at setUpControl (forms.js:3181)
>       at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:7345)
>       at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:8070)
>       at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7993)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31906)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar um controle dentro de grupo de controles você precisa definir primeiro o grupo e depois chamar o control

Você pode usar a diretiva `formGroupName` que funciona como o `formControlName`, porém o controle deve ser um grupo:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
    <div formGroupName="aluno">
        <input formControlName="id"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Você também pode usar a diretiva `formGroup` assim como usado no elemento `form`:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
    <div [formGroup]="formulario.controls.aluno">
        <input formControlName="id"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Desconheço que o Angular entenda o ponto (`.`) como um sub controle de um grupo. O Angular até entende na API JavaScript: `formulario.get('controle.subcontrole')` mas não no HTML

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu certo!